# Can crosswalk be added to the Trigger.io tool chain?

Tags: android, google-chrome, trigger.io, crosswalk-runtime

Crosswalk (https://crosswalk-project.org) is a package recently released by Intel that embeds Chromium directly into an Android app to provide a consistent web view across all versions of Android phones. Is this something trigger.io can and/or is planning to add to their portfolio of options?  The potential benefits, given the issues with older Android webviews, is significant enough to motivate us to take on the cost of managing the Cordova toolchain ourselves and drop our use of Trigger.IO.  Alternatively, is this something that could be done as a plugin/extension to Trigger.IO?

Thank you,
Ian

Comment: I'd like to see that as well. @antoine-van-gelder any info on this?

Comment: It seems like **PhoneGap** is currently in the progress of adding this as an easy on/off option for their tools: http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/why-do-not-provide-the-compile-with-crosswalk-html5-webview-for-android-feature-in-phonegap-build-and-phonegap-cli - I could imagine it would be a nice thing for marketing to have it implemented before they do :)

Comment: We're working on it, watch this space :-)

Comment: Looks like they've released a beta with crosswalk support: https://trigger.io/docs/current/api/beta_release_notes.html

Answer (score 1):

Trigger have released the beta of their crosswalk support in v2.3.1-beta. Looks like performance improvements means its worthwhile using it, no matter which version of Android you intend to support. It won't be made official release for a while until we in the community test it out a bit.

Check out their blog post: http://trigger.io/cross-platform-application-development-blog/2015/04/02/solving-android-fragmentation-with-trigger-io-forge-and-intels-crosswalk/